# Triple click select loses newline

Tags: xorg, mouse

I'm very used to a triple-click selecting a whole line in any program -
 including the next newline. On my fresh Ubuntu 16.04.2 installation the triple click does not select the trailing newline.

I did like this feature very much, how do I re-enable it?

Inspired by [the Unix & Linux question "How to configure the double click behavior in an X terminal?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45925) , I already tried to create a `.Xresources` file containing

```
XTerm*VT100.cutNewLine: true
XTerm*VT100.cutToBeginningOfLine: true
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: I don't remember triple clicking selecting a trailing newline, on anything: xfce, gnome, mate, Ubuntu, Mint, Windows... it usually selects a line/paragraph only to the end of the paragraph text, not trailing newlines. I haven't used Ubuntu unity, is that what you're using, and it's supposed to do that?

Comment: Maybe it's a Unity thing? One specific example is triple click-selecting command lines in Chrome and then both pasting and executing them in the terminal at the same time with the middle mouse button.

Comment: I've done that before, but usually have to **move the mouse** some to select more lines. Then the newlines are copied successfully - it just never copies the *very last* newline, I thought that's what you were asking about, specifically the very last newline at the end of a line or paragraph. Are you not?

Comment: I was talking about pointing the mouse at one point on a line, for example the command-not-found (`Try: sudo apt install <selected package>`) line in bash. Then triple-click and middle click and it would just execute that. I did just find out that it actually does work as expected in bash, but not in zsh or gedit.